# CGI script wont execute from HTML page

Tags: python, cgi

based off the example from this Wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

This is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="add.cgi" method="POST">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Enter two numbers to add</legend>
     <label>First Number: <input type="number" name="num1"></label><br/>
     <label>Second Number: <input type="number" name="num2"></label><br/>
   </fieldset>
   <button>Add</button>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and this is the CGI code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

input_data = cgi.FieldStorage()

print('Content-Type: text/html') # HTML is following
print('')                         # Leave a blank line
print('<h1>Addition Results</h1>')
try:
    num1 = int(input_data["num1"].value)
    num2 = int(input_data["num2"].value)
except:
    print('<output>Sorry, the script cannot turn your inputs into numbers (integers).</output>')
    raise SystemExit(1)
print('<output>{0} + {1} = {2}</output>'.format(num1, num2, num1 + num2))
```

I enter into the HTML site, and I see this

[HTML Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNj2j.jpg)

Then when I enter two numbers I return this,

[Web CGI Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nECn.jpg)

I don't know why it wont work, any ideas?

EDIT: Attached is my directory for Apache and the configuration for Apache

[Directory for Apache config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIVTR.jpg)
[Apache Config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXc5I.jpg)

Comment: CGI requires configuration on your http server software. Which server software (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.) are you using? What's your configuration?

Comment: @yume_chan thank you for replying, I've attached my config file for Apache and the config file

Comment: Please read [ask]. Don't post pictures of text.

Comment: Typo: You told Apache to execute `.py` files as CGI but your HTML shows you have a `.cgi` file and not a `.py` file.